# Rails URL with custom identifier (not id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a Rails app for managing individual items. Each item has an item number (zero padded, 4 digit number, e.g. `0002` or `0212` or `1002`), which I would like to use in the urls for the application. If I currently navigate to `/items/2` I get the item with `id = 2` and not the item with `item_number = 2`. My routes.rb file contains only `resources :items`; how would I go about allowing for this to pull out the items by item number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override the `to_param` method in your Item model:

```
def to_param
    item_number.to_s
end
```

You don't have to change anything in your routes.
You'll just have to find the items using `find_by_item_number(params[:id])`

---

Just so you know: if you wanted to display the name of the item in the url, you could do the following:

```
def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name}".parameterize
end
```

What's great about that, is that "1-item-name".to_i is `1`! So you would not have to change your find methods everywhere.

Comment: You wrote verbatim what I was going to say. Good answer :)

Comment: i would also recommend to create a class-method called `find_by_param` as a companion

Comment: Thanks Robin, I've just added the to_param to return number, and updated my item controller @item = Item.find_by_number(params[:id]), but am getting a NoMethodError of private method `split' called for 1023:Fixnum when I navigate to /items/1023

Comment: Ok, so it has to be `def to_param; item_number.to_s` end :)

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the `item_path` helper (that you get for free by defining `resources :items`) uses the item's id to construct the url:

```
item = Item.find(1)
item_path(item) # => "/items/1", i.e. the same result as calling item_path(item.id)
```

It does this "magic" by calling the to_param instance method on the Item class, which by default returns the item's id.

So if you want something else, you have to override the to_param method. In your case, you could do something like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    item_number
  end
end
```

And then:

```
item = Item.find_by_item_id('0001')
item_path(item) # => "/users/0001"
```